# Does storyboard support Push Pop operations?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uistoryboard

I am working on storyboards and am including the Oauth library 1.0 to authenticate users.

The Library contains some push pop operations to their .xib files. Will the navigation be supported as i have main storyboard for iphone.

Or will I have to recreate the views for those library classes in my storyboard to allow this?

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks
Vikas

Comment: Storyboard supports all features as xib does, the only difference between them is storyboard is the collection of xibs and their transition.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as stated above, all xib features are supported in storyboards. They're just used slightly differently...

To programmatically push, you can use this:

```
   UIViewController *myController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"myID"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:myController animated:YES];
```

[image]

And use this to pop to root:

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: HI the code you provided me is for linking a viewcontroller which is already added inside the Storyboards or to be added in story board but i want to push from a viewcontroller which is inside storyboard to a view controller which has .xib file

Comment: @VikasOjha You can't do that directly in the storyboard. You'll have to load the view controller that is associated with your xib in code and load it the traditional way. Otherwise you'll have to move your view from the xib into the storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

A storyboard is a mechanism for defining view controllers, it also allows you to define transitions between those view controllers, but it does not limit you to those view controllers.

You're free to mix storyboards with view controllers created from any other source - both XIBs and code.

Create the view controllers from the library any way you see fit, and present them. Pushing the view controllers onto an existing navigation controller from the storyboard, or running them modally are both valid ways to get the view controllers from the static library into your app.